# get document Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when I'm trying to get the document from this view I have the error

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value in the line that start with `db1.collection...`.

But if I try the same get document in another view it goes

What is wrong here?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class DetailPlantViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var detailTableView: UITableView!
    
    var queryPlantData: String?
    
    var db1:Firestore!
    var plantDataArray = [PlantData]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        detailTableView.delegate = self
        detailTableView.dataSource = self
        detailTableView.register(MyDetailTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: MyDetailTableViewCell.identifier)
        tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Log Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logOutPressed))
        
      
        
        db1.collection("plants").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if error == nil && snapshot != nil{
                for document in snapshot!.documents{
                    let documentData = document.data()
                    print(documentData)
                }
            }
        }
        //loadPlantData()
    }
```

Comment: That line of code won't throw that error (assuming db1 is populated) - something in the closure perhaps. However this `//loadPlantData()` may be an issue if you plan on working with the returned firebase data at that point. Anything following a firebase closure will execute before the code in the closure due to the asynchronous nature of Firebase. Can you please add a breakpoint and step through you code line by line until you get that error and update the question with more details?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `db1` anywhere? You need to set that with `db1 = Firestore.firestore()` or however you are accessing the `Firestore` object.

This should be done before you access the collection

```
db1.collection("plants")...
```

Comment: Yes it is set I have wrongly deleted the line when I pasted it here but there’s

Comment: I have a first table view and here the code work after when I click in a row it has goest on this view another table view but here the code give that error

Comment: can you edit and put that line back?